# Python Flask send_static_file not showing progress bar in chrome

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/send_static_file")
def send_static_file:
    file_name = "a.db.gz"
    return app.send_static_file(file_name)
```

send_static_file is not showing progress bar in chrome. I don't see Content-Length response header in Chrome's Inspect tool but in curl its showing the response header.

Comment: What version of Flask are you using. The current version (0.10) should set the Content-Length header in all circumstances. Are you 100% certain it is missing? (use `curl -D - -o /dev/null http://example.com` to echo the headers received).

Comment: You are right actually. Content-Length is coming. Only the chrome's inspect tool is not showing the Content-Length nor progress status. What could be the reason?

Comment: In curl, I get Content-Length. But in the java code, the Content-Length is missing and it comes as -1.  URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();                int lengthOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

Comment: No idea; not Flask's fault however, as it is sending you the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from flask import make_response
import os

@app.route("/send_static_file")
def send_static_file:
    file_name = "a.db.gz"
    response = make_response(app.send_static_file(file_name))
    response.headers['content-length'] = str(os.path.getsize(file_name)))
    return response
```